# Join columns from one table to single column from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to learn how to join multiple columns from one table to a single column from another table.

This is my table structure in its simplest form:

**teams**

```
   id | team_name |
   1  |   teamA   |
   2  |   teamB   |
   3  |   teamC   |
   4  |   teamD   |
```

There is a table named "TeamInOut"

```
      In    |   Out  
      -     |   teamA 
    teamB   |     -  
      -     |   teamC  
    teamD   |     -   
      -     |   teamD
```

The results I want to get back would be:

```
      In    |   Out    |teamid
      -     |   teamA  |  1
    teamB   |     -    |  2
      -     |   teamC  |  3
    teamD   |     -    |  4
      -     |   teamD  |  4
```

My question is, how do I create teamid column? Please help me.

Comment: Simply join TeamInOut and teams.

Comment: @jarlh : can you show me the way?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Inner_join

Answer (score 2):

Here is the Query you need but better to learn how to do it  :

```
Declare @Team Table ( id int , team_name varchar(50))
Declare @TeaminOut table (ins varchar(50) , outs varchar(50))

insert into @Team
select 1 , 'teamA' union 
select 2 , 'teamB' union 
select 3 , 'teamC' union 
select 4 , 'teamD' 

insert into @TeaminOut
select '-', 'teamA' union
select 'teamB', '-' union
select '-', 'teamc' union
select 'teamD', '-' union
select '-', 'teamD'
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

select tio.ins , tio.outs , t.id
from @Team as t
inner join @TeaminOut as tio   ON t.team_name = tio.ins or  t.team_name = tio.outs
order by id
```

here is the results

[image]

good luck

Answer (score -2):

SELECT * FROM Teams JOIN TeamInOut

Comment: Will not return the wanted result.

Comment: i edited my answer go try it

Comment: Syntax error... Just a tip, create the tables, insert the data and try the queries.

Comment: `JOIN` needs an `ON` clause to specify the joining relationship.